# Get access to all terms associated to each post that the wp_query loop displays

Tags: wp-query, terms

If the following loop logic gives me access to post properties that are associated to a CPT (for example, 'sports')...

```php
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'sports',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
      );
      $query = new WP_Query($args);


      if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

         //All the stuff I do...
```

Then from within the loop, how can I also query for all terms that are associated to each of these 'sports' posts?

- Under this 'sports' CPT, I have 3 taxonomies ('basketball', 'volleyball', 'baseball').
- Each of these taxonomies have multiple terms under them.
- I want each post that is provided from this wp_query loop, to have access to all the terms that are associated to their own post, and write them out (i.e. `print_r $query->terms_array`) from within the loop;

Is this possible?

I tried placing the following code inside my loop, but it turns out to be invalid...

```php
   <?php
          $terms = get_terms(get_the_ID(), array(
            'basketball',
            'volleyball',
            'baseball'
          ));
          $terms = join(', ', wp_list_pluck($terms, 'name'));
          echo  '<pre>'  .  var_export($terms, true) .  '</pre>';
          ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/), which..

> Retrieves the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post.

You could for example have helper functions like these,

```
// functions.php
function my_sports_post_terms( int $post_id ) : array {
  $taxonomies = ['basketball', 'volleyball', 'baseball'];
  $terms = [];

  foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
    $terms[$taxonomy] = my_sports_post_tax_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);
  }

  return $terms;
}

// Force array return value as get_the_terms() may not always return an array
function my_sports_post_tax_terms( int $post_id, string $taxonomy ) : array {
  $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
  return $terms && is_array($terms) ? $terms : [];
}
```

And then use the first one in the Loop like so.

```
// some template file
while ($query->have_posts()) {
  $query->the_post();

  $terms = my_sports_post_terms( get_the_ID() );

  // code..
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, looking into this...

Comment: Thank you for understanding my problem.  That was exactly what I needed!  I can now see all terms associated to each post, from within my loop.  Much appreciated for your care and service!